# Tax when employed in UK, living in Austria or Germany

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, european-union, working-abroad

I am employed by a UK-based on profit on a remote contract. If I were to move to Germany or Austria as an EU citizen, and continue working remotely at my UK job, what would be the tax implications. Would I need to pay tax in both the UK and either Germany or Austria?

Answer (score 1):

Without having read those specific tax treaties, the general rule is that tax is due where you perform the work, especially if you also live in that country or if the employer has a permanent establishment in that country.

So if you move to Germany and work from there, you must tax your global income in Germany. The UK would have no grounds to tax you, since you're neither working nor living in the UK.

But it's not just a matter of taxes. It's also a matter of worker's rights, insurance, and social security. If you work in Germany, your employment relationship would have to be subject to German rules. Most employers foreign employers are not set up to do this. Self-employment is not generally an alternative since Germany has rules similar to the UK's IR35. But there are some companies that can serve as your employer of record in Germany, for a price. You could also elect to handle the employment bureaucracy yourself (like deducting your own taxes) but that's noticeably more effort.

The same applies *mutatis mutandis* for other EU countries like Austria.

Comment: Not your global income, but your income while present in Germany. Your global income is used to calculate the percentage of salary that you should pay; you pay that percentage on income you made while your bum was in Germany.

Comment: @gnasher729 For the case of “unbeschränkte Steuerpflicht” I'd rather phrase it as getting a tax rebate for foreign-paid tax. There is no double taxation, but the total taxes will always be at least as much as if all of the money had been earned in Germany. The “unbeschränkte Steuerpflicht” case applies if OP is resident in Germany, which would seem to be the case. Things would be different when earning German income while living outside of Germany.